# Spring Certification Questions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask such questions. But I really need the info to make decision for Spring Framework certifications.

After googling a lot I found that there 3 categories of Spring Certification

- **Spring Professional (Core Spring 4.2.x or 4.1.x or 3.2.x versions)**
- **Spring Specialist (Enterprise Integration with Spring)**
- **Spring Expert (Hibernate with Spring)**

Can someone tell me above list still valid list ? Does it worth to go for it? I also don't find much online resource / practice /MCQ for this certification and it makes me in doubts.

Experts: Please provide me links / resources for practise (may be MCQ's / Dumps).

Note: I know spring is one of most widely used Java framework in an industry, but not sure what is advantageous being a certified. Please guide

Comment: @chrylis We do not accept education and career advice questions on Programmers. I see that you aren't an active user on Programmers - please do not suggest sites to other people if you don't understand the community there. It leads to cross-posting of off-topic or low quality questions that end up being down voted and closed, which leads to a poor user experience.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Noted.